# Julia OrdinaryDiffEq: progress_message defaults are not what they claim to be

Tags: julia

In [OrdinaryDiffEq's solve.jl](https://github.com/SciML/OrdinaryDiffEq.jl/blob/3021916e201439166197f589b38d3a81949061ce/src/solve.jl), supposedly the default for `progress_message` is `ODE_DEFAULT_PROG_MESSAGE` (line 58), which by default is set to show dt, t, and the maximum of u [as stated here](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqBase.jl/blob/2daa81bfeb3df95c43469b96c058877a9cc240da/src/common_defaults.jl) (lines 21-22). However, I'm using it with TerminalLoggers to run the code in Jupyter Lab and/or terminal, and instead, I'm getting the message "ETA: (some time number)".

```
using Logging: global_logger
using TerminalLoggers: TerminalLogger
global_logger(TerminalLogger())
using OrdinaryDiffEq

function lorenz(du,u,p,t)
 du[1] = 10.0*(u[2] - u[1])
 du[2] = u[1]*(28.0 - u[3]) - u[2]
 du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0; 0.0; 0.0]
tspan = (0.0, 100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz, u0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob, Tsit5(), progress=true)
```

Terminal output:

```sh
ODE   0%|                                               |  ETA: N/A
ODE  77%|████████████████████████████████████▎          |  ETA: 0:00:00
ODE 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████| Time: 0:00:01
```

The ETA seems to be part of the [TerminalLoggers defaults](https://github.com/c42f/TerminalLoggers.jl/search?q=ETA).

The [documentation](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/common_solver_opts/#Progress-Monitoring) is relatively terse and doesn't explain what to pass to the `progress_message` solver option to change the message. Passing strings like `progress_message="dt"` doesn't work. Passing in the exact function for `ODE_DEFUALT_PROG_MESSAGE` as defined in DiffEqBase.jl/src/common_defaults.jl does not change the behavior at all.

Is this a mistake for which I should file an issue with OrdinaryDiffEq, or is there some way I can manipulate `progress_message` in the common solver options to actually get dt, t, and u?

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation is relatively terse and doesn't explain what to pass to the progress_message solver option to change the message. Passing strings like progress_message="dt" doesn't work. Passing in the exact function for ODE_DEFUALT_PROG_MESSAGE as defined in DiffEqBase.jl/src/common_defaults.jl does not change the behavior at all.

These options work on any logger which supports them. The default logger in Juno(/Atom) supports it and uses these messages. I do not think TerminalLoggers does, which is an issue of TerminalLoggers.